# locale attribute in convertNumber tag in XHTML not working in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jsf, number-formatting

I am using primefaces in my application for UI and in one of the table I have a column for currency in dollar.

Below is the column tag in xhtml, the expected behavior is that whenever the value is negative then it should be displayed as ($value) in UI.

For example if the value is coming as -0.85 then it should be displayed as ($0.84) in UI.
This I have achieved using the locale attribute in convertNumber tag. If the locale attribute is set to "en-US" then this conversion is achieved.

The application is deployed in Jboss and everything is working as expected.

But recently I have moved from Jboss to Tomcat and this conversion is not working now, I am getting the value as -$0.87 in UI when deployed to Tomcat which is not what I need. It should be same as how it was working in Jboss.

Please let me know how to fix this

```
<p:column exportable="true">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputLabel value="Difference" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{CurrencyVar.Amt}"
  style="float:right;">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" locale="en-US"
    maxFractionDigits="2" />
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: @mplungjan: sorry but that's completely unrelated.

Comment: @Deepu: run in a plain vanilla Java class in both environments using the same JDK as used for the respective server: `System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(-0.85));`. If this also gives diff then it's definitely not a JSF problem.

Comment: @mplungjan: because same problem is definitely reproducible without PrimeFaces. If you knew how `<f:convertNumber>` internally works then you should already long have known that JSF is merely the messenger of whatever output returned by JDK and that PrimeFaces is merely the look'n'feel.

Comment: @BalusC : I had run the above print statement in plain java class and it returns the same value -$0.85. But I am still doubting that is it something to do with the server jboss and tomcat because we have not made any other changes in the java side or UI side apart from the server change. Is it like I need to add some extra configuration for Tomcat ? or anything else I need to check on ?

Comment: Yeah it will print that when you run it with the JDK as used by Tomcat. You should also run that class with same JDK as used by JBoss (which is most probably an older JDK8 version possibly of a different vendor). If that works then you have 100% confirmation that it's got nothing to do with JBoss/Tomcat/JSF/PrimeFaces/HTML/XHTML etc and that you just need to replace/upgrade the JDK. If that's not an option then you'll most likely need to supply a custom converter and/or a fixed pattern in order to be JDK independent.

Comment: @BalusC : I have written a custom converter class and did the logic need for my conversion. It is now working as expected. Thanks very much for your valuable comments. Really appreciate.